# Can RDP mirror/shadow the local console session? (re: Win7, RDP, and HTPCs)

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop, htpc, remote-access

I'm a huge fan of the built-in Remote Desktop in Windows but it seems to have a huge limitation for me in regards to a HTPC.

Sometimes I need to login to my HTPC and be able to change the display resolution, sound settings, etc.  However, if I use RDP it doesn't allow me to set the desktop/local resolution nor can I even see the sound card settings.

I'd love to use RDP so is it possible to get around this limitation?

Do I have to use something like VNC?  (I'm hesitant about using VNC because I'm not sure how it would affect the nVidia drivers and Bluray 3D playback, etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know on server you can connect to the console by opening mstsc /console, I tested this with 7 and sadly it does not work. You will have to use VNC if you want to mimic the console session. I would recommend Team viewer I leave games of civ open on my home desktop and will take a turn etc. while on the road when I get to the hotel, or before dinner. It never affects my drivers and I can pick the game back up when I get home without any problems. It is also free for personal use and has a lot of nice features like remote reboot into safe mode (I find this nice when helping friends with PC issues). By the way I have an Nvidia card as well if that makes you feel any better about trying VNC.

Comment: The `/console` switch has been replaced by `/admin`.

Comment: It still doesn't let you change the resolution, win 7 still knows it is a RDP session.