# Remote Desktop in Windows XP - How to share desktop with the local user?

Tags: remote

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Remote desktop connection without locking the remote computer](https://superuser.com/questions/80334/remote-desktop-connection-without-locking-the-remote-computer)

I have Windows XP Professional Edition SP 2 - 32 bit. I have read other threads which show how to bypass the limitation for a single concurrent user, by applying a patch. While that will work, it will only allow 2 concurrent users (1 local and 1 remote) to have separate sessions. What I want is to work collaboratively with the local user, so that he can see what I am doing and vice versa.

I know of third party tools like RAdmin, TeamViewer, LogMeIn, etc etc, but I want to know, is there a way (any patch or hack) which can make it work in Remote Desktop over a LAN without requiring internet.

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remote desktop connection without locking the remote computer](http://superuser.com/questions/80334/remote-desktop-connection-without-locking-the-remote-computer) and/or [Can RDP mirror/shadow the local console session?](http://superuser.com/questions/238891/can-rdp-mirror-shadow-the-local-console-session-re-win7-rdp-and-htpcs)

Comment: I read exactly that thread before posting here. But I wanted to re-ask this question, as the other thread does not give a definitive answer within the scope of my question.

Comment: Just becuase the answers aren't what you want doesn't make it a different question.  I'd suggest picking one (the 2nd one I linked is more suited IMO), offer a bounty on it and comment on why you'd like further answers.  See [Set a bounty on a question](http://superuser.com/privileges/set-bounties) for more info.

Comment: Do you do know about Windows' [Remote Assistance](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-CA/windows7/What-is-Windows-Remote-Assistance)?

Comment: well I guess I already got the answer from SLaks below. Will just wait some time, before accepting it as answer. And, I guess now, it was worth posting this question (even though possible duplicate), as many users will find it helpful, I hope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for the remote control feature:

1. Connect to the remote machine as a different user
2. Open Task Manager
3. Go to the Users tab
4. Right-click the first user
5. Click Remote Control

Comment: You mean apply patch to make Remote Desktop support concurrent sessions, then remote login into machine and then do the steps you mentioned above? Really, is there such a thing as Remote Control in Task Manager->Users tab. Never knew! Have you tried it? (I am not able to try it immediately)

Comment: @AllSolutions: Yes to all of your questions.